# Different usages of ! in an if statement

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what's the difference between using `!` like this:

```
if (!a === b) {
//code here
}
```

or like this:

```
if (a !== b) {
//code here
}
```

Can somebody please elaborate on this? Are there any performance differences? I've seen people use both and I'd like to know what's better to use. Thanks.

Comment: "not **a** equal to **b**" vs "**a** not equal to **b**"

Comment: I believe `!a` would transform the left side to a boolean and then do an equality check against `b`. `a !== b`  is an inverse equality check of a to b.

Comment: The first one is basically saying "if a is falsy and false equals b" whereas the second one says "if a is not equal to b"

Comment: "*Are there any performance differences?*" is this a bottleneck for your application? If no, stop premature micro optimisations.

Comment: Figure out performance differences on your own using `performance.now()` before and after the command(s). I recommend doing it on Chrome since it's more precise.

Comment: @Rojo first off, there are semantic differences. Second, micro-benchmarking this is very likely to yield very unreliable results.

Comment: @VLAZ my main goal in including that was to prevent the OP from asking performance questions here in the future. They'll get weird numbers, realize they're about the same, and hopefully realize that it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Rojo or they'll get weird numbers, get mislead by them and then reach the wrong conclusion. We have plenty of bad questions and answers posted here which are based on flawed performance testing.

Comment: I think you meant `(! (a === b))` wich is equals to `(a !== b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!a` would nagate the value of `a`
If a contain any `falsy` value then `!a` results `true` else vice versa and then check for equality with `b`

```
if (!a === b) {
  //code here
}
```

Here the code block runs when `a` is not equal to `b`;

```
if (a !== b) {
//code here
}
```

Let's consider both case and suppose a = false, b = true

`(!a === b)` => `!(false) === true` => `true === true` => equal so code blocks run

`(a !== b)`  => `false !== true` => equal so code blocks run

But when a = false and b = false

`(!a === b)` => `!(false) === false` => `true === false` => not equal so code blocks `doesn't`  run

`(a !== b)`  => `false !== false` => not equal so code blocks `doesn't` run

With respect to performance, there is almost no difference.

```js
const a = true,
  b = true;
const firstStart = performance.now();
if (!a === b) {
  //code here
}
const firstEnd = performance.now();
console.log(firstEnd - firstStart);

const secondStart = performance.now();
if (a !== b) {
  //code here
}
const secondEnd = performance.now();
console.log(secondEnd - secondStart);
```

Comment: "*Results of both are same*" **ONLY** if you do this with booleans. It's not necessarily the same if you have different data types. `!null === false` is `false` but `null !== false` is `true`. The two operations are *not* equivalent.

Comment: `!null === false` results to `false` and `null !== false` to `true` You mistakenly switched the results.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised this after re-reading the commend and edited it.